# How to create loading screen for node-webkit?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

I have created a [node-webkit](http://nwjs.io/) desktop app but it takes long time to load after I click `.exe`. Is there any way to show loading screen. I am searching for a solution for this but I didn't get one.

Answer (score 1):

To show a loading screen or a splash screen when your main application screen is loading consider the following steps:

1. Start your application with main window set to hidden.
2. Since your main window is hidden, open another window which will act as a splash screen or loading screen.
3. When your main application is loaded completely and ready, close the splash screen window and display your main window which was hidden.

---

**Step 1** To start your application with main window hidden:

Set `show: false` of Window property in your [manifest](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/manifest-format)

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "description": "demo app of node-webkit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "keywords": [ "demo", "node-webkit" ],
  "window": {
    "title": "node-webkit demo",
    "icon": "link.png",
    "show": false,
    "toolbar": false,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500,
    "position": "mouse",
    "min_width": 400,
    "min_height": 200
  }
}
```

`"show": false` property will not display the main window when your application will start.

**Step 2** Open loading or splash window:

Write a script in your index.html that will open another window which will act as a splash screen.

```
var guiWin = require('nw.gui');   
this.splashScreen = guiWin.open('path/to/splash.html', {
                "transparent": true,
                'frame': false,
                "icon": "path/to/icon.png",
                'position': 'center',
                'always-on-top': true,
                "width": 475,
                "height": 250,
                "resizable": false,
                "toolbar": false,
                "fullscreen": false
            });
```

**Step 3**. Close the splash screen and show main window when app is ready:

When your main application is loaded completely, you can close the splash window and show the main window by calling this method.

```
function hideSplash() {
    this._splashScreen.close(true);
    guiWin.get().show();            // get the current window and show
    this.splashScreen = null;            
}
```

Comment: hai thank for your response.!!! but it didn't work because my application contain some assets folder nearly 1GB it takes time to load index.html itself i think after that only it will execute step 2. my package size is heavy. which i have kept my assets folder inside .exe because of some content security. i don't how to overcome this issue

Comment: Is that your index.html is loaded by nwjs late or if its getting late loading all your resources? can you try writing that script in <head> so that it will open new window first and then load other resources

Comment: the goal for the splash screen is to help with the user's patience, but the way you implement it, will  still require some waiting, somethin independant is needed for that

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for:

> This is a small library to show a splash screen until main application loads.
>
> The splash screen will run in a separate process so any animations
> will play smoothly while the app is loading.

https://github.com/nwutils/nw-splasher

Comment: If the wait time is from your code, then this will work. If the wait time is from waiting for NW.js to load up chromium/node, then this library will still have to wait for NW.js to load before it can start showing a splash screen. A common cause of NW.js taking longer to open is people packaging a zipped version of there app with it. There is no benefit to this, it just requires NW.js to unzip the code every time before the app can be displayed. So if you're doing that, changing the way you package your app will solve the issue without need for a splash screen.

Comment: @Jaredcheeda I wasn't aware of "people packaging a zipped version of there app with it", and i'm wondering why would people do that. Obviously if the app has a counter-productive design, that also must be fixed for better performance. That was good to know thanks for your input.

Comment: @Jaredcheeda about the wait time induced by NW.JS itself, well there is no way to overcome that except to write a complete different program in a language like C/C++ or C#... and i'm sure few people will be willing to do that.